# CAD mechanical bonds and kinematics

Tags: autocad, cad

Is there a CAD format, which allows to describe mechanical bonds between objects (axes, joints, springs, etc.) and/or motion of objects ?

Comment: This question is a bit broad - but why should it matter? Is there a reason you can't devise your own file format? Or are you asking so you can take inspiration from how an existing file format does it?

Comment: I want to apply a force to a system of rigid bodies with mechanical bonds, and see how it evolves over time. Of course, I can devise my own file format, but I am not sure that nobody has done it so far.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any personal CAD experience, but 3D objects can be defined using edges and nodes/vertices which reduces the problem to a [graph-representation issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)#Representations). 3D models defined using other techniques (such as composed functions or a filter pipeline, such as `B-spline > Lathe or extrude > Transformation > Material/texture`) will have considerably different means of serialization to file.

Storing motion is a separate issue entirely - and also complicated by the many different ways to represent animation, and if your system uses any kind of skeletal basis or solid-body physics/animation. Then there's keyframed and parameterised animation. Are you using an inverse-kinematics system too?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific about why you need such CAD format?
Without really knowing what you are after, I think the closer thing to what you are asking for is Finite Element analysis programs like ANSYS, ABAQAS, etc. They work in CAD like environment  and allow adding many types of elements to simulate dynamic (motion) anaylses and many other type of analysis. They include a huge variety of elements like linear springs are rltational springs.. etc.